# ARCore : Get Camera's resolution

Tags: android, android-camera, arcore

Is there any way to get camera's resolution ? (unless using Android from scratch)
I did not found any getter, on a setter on session.setDisplayGeometry() that is not really what I expect.

My goal is to know the camera's picture ratio to cropp it on my display since the screen and the camera do not use the same size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to access the camera's resolution through the ARCore API in the developer preview. I asked about the resolution in comments of a separate question and it looks like the [camera resolution in the developer preview will always be 1920x1080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949769/accessing-image-data-bytes-in-arcore#comment78942778_45987608).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the resolution of the camera:

```
Frame frame = session.update();
Camera camera = frame.getCamera();
int dim[] = camera.getImageIntrinsics().getImageDimensions();
Log.d("ARCORE","Camera Dimensions: "+dim[0]+" x "+dim[1]);
```

But it only gives me 640x480, and I don't think there's any way to change it right now, though it may use different values on different hardware.
(ARCore 1.3)

I know it's an old question, but the answer seems to have changed since then.

Comment: Update Sep 2020 on my Samsung S20+ : still gives 640x480... I don't understand to chat correspond the values given by this API...

Comment: If you use `frame.acquireCameraImage()` and get width and depth of that image, it returns 640x480 in Galaxy Note8, too.