# ARCore Android Studio add filter to camera view

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

I'm trying to add filter such as sobel edge detection to ARCore on Android Studio SDK.

Currently I'm using

```
GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
```

to read the image from the glsurfaceview every frame and adding the filter using GPU-Image Android.

But it is causing performance issue such as frame drop and eventually a crash.
What is the best way to access image data in ARCore?

I see that the BackgroundRenderer from ARCore is rendering the camera view but I don't see where it's getting the camera texture from.
How do you put the filtered image back to the ARCore camera preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a good way to do this yet. [They are aware of the limitation](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/30), and personally I'm hoping they add frame access functionality sooner rather than later.

In the interim, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987608/1445599) may help you with frame capture. I've implemented PBO writes, and I can capture frames at around 15 fps without too much visible latency.

> For the time being, your best bet for accessing image data is probably drawing the texture to a renderbuffer and using glReadPixels into a persistent-mapped pixel unpack buffer.  Use a fence sync to detect when the glReadPixels is complete.
>
> Another option is to use a compute shader and write directly to a <strike>persistent-mapped</strike> SSBO.  *(Disregard persistent-mapped suggestion.  I thought `EXT_buffer_storage` had broader support)*
>
> The later is possibly fewer copies (the renderbuffer pixels may still hit DRAM even if you invalidate it after the glReadPixels), but it's also a less-common code path and incurs render/compute changeovers so I don't have intuition about which approach would be more efficient.

Comment: Can you give an example of how PBO writes can be achieved?
I'm using byte buffer like this:
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570710/android-opengl-es-3-0-pbo-instead-of-glreadpixels) is essentially how I've implemented mine. You'll need some sort of init function to create the OpenGL buffers on the first call though. Page 9 [of this presentation](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2014-siggraph-bof/KITE-BOF_Aug14.pdf) has some good examples on how to generate buffers.

Comment: I have implemented PBO successfully, but I'm not seeing any performance gain at all compared to glReadPixels() without PBO. I'm able to achieve 30 fps on Google Pixel 2 with or without PBO. I'm not using fence sync in my project right now, could that be a factor in improving the performance? @deeroh